# golang: read file generator

Tags: python, go, generator

I'm learning *go* language and try to rewrite some of my Python code using golang.
I wrote a generator function that reads a text file line by line and send (using *yield* keyword) only "valid" lines (blank lines are ignored, uncompleted lines are recomposed).

Sample file (myfile.txt):

```
#123= FOOBAR(1.,'text');

#126= BARBAZ('poeazpfodsp',
234,56);
```

parse.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
def validlines(filename):
    with open(filename) as fdin:
        buff = ''
        for line in fdin.readlines():
            line = line.strip()
            if line == '':
                continue
            buff += line
            if line[-1] != ';':
                continue
            yield buff
            buff = ''
        fdin.close()

for line in validlines('myfile.txt'):
    print(line)
```

displays:

```
#123= FOOBAR(1.,'text');
#126= BARBAZ('poeazpfodsp',234,56);
```

Now, I try to do it the same way using a closure in golang:

parse.go:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func validLines(filename string) (func() (string, bool)) {

    file, _ := os.Open(filename)
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)

    return func() (string, bool) {
        buff := ""
        for scanner.Scan() {
            line := scanner.Text()
            line = strings.TrimSpace(line)

            if line == "" {
                continue
            }
            buff += line
            if line[len(line)-1] != ';' {
                continue
            }
            return buff, true
        }

        file.Close()
        return "", false
    }
}

func main() {
    vline := validLines("myfile.txt")
    for line, ok := vline(); ok; {
        fmt.Println(line)
    }
}
```

displays:

```
#123= FOOBAR(1.,'text');
#123= FOOBAR(1.,'text');
#123= FOOBAR(1.,'text');
#123= FOOBAR(1.,'text');
#123= FOOBAR(1.,'text');
#123= FOOBAR(1.,'text');
#123= FOOBAR(1.,'text');
...
```

What's the right way to do it in golang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the `for` loop of your main which is the problem. With this syntax, here is what it does:

1. Initialize `line` and `ok` with a first call to `vline()`
2. If `ok` is true, run the loop once
3. Update something at the end of the block, and go to 2.

So, your problem is that you never update `line`and `ok`. Here is the correct version:

```
for line, ok := vline(); ok; line, ok = vline() { ... }
```

Comment: I was looking for the problem in validLines function, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

In Go you can use channels instead of yield, it's very convenient.

package main

```
import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func ValidLines(filename string) (c chan string) {
    c = make(chan string)
    buff := ""
    go func() {
        file, err := os.Open(filename)
        if err != nil {
            close(c)
            return
        }

        reader := bufio.NewReader(file)
        for {
            line, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
            if err != nil {
                close(c)
                return
            }
            line = strings.TrimSpace(line)
            if line == "" {
                continue
            }
            buff += line
            if line[len(line)-1] != ';' {
                continue
            }
            c <- buff
            buff = ""
        }
    }()
    return c
}

func main() {
    for line := range ValidLines("myfile.txt") {
        fmt.Println(line)
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest `defer close(c)` at the top of your anonymous function.

Answer (score 2):

Just little addition to [pav5000's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37458864/7873082), you should make the channel buffered:
c := make(chan string, 1)
Otherwise, it will be reading the whole file into a channel and there is no point in using it.

Answer (score 1):

small change:

```
func main() {
    vline := validLines("myfile.txt")
    line, ok := vline()
    for ok  {
        fmt.Println(line)
        line, ok = vline()
    }
}
```